# Return the last sub sorted row in a table (sql)

Tags: sql

It's quiet hard to describe this problem but it's easy to see it graphically:

```
    x    y
    1    1
    2    1
    3    1
  * 4    1 *
    5    2
  * 6    2 * 
    7    3    
    8    3
    9    3
 * 10    3 *
```

I have sorted a table by x, then sub-sorted by y. I need to return the x value of the last item in the sub-sorted table (the stared rows).

I'm aware of the LAST command, but I don't know how to apply this recursively i.e. to each sub-sorted section.

Best,

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT y, Max(x) FROM [table] group by Y
```